# X509CertificateValidationMode not working in Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, wcf, docker, .net-core

I have a service written in .NET Core which works splendidly on Windows, but fails to run with the exception included at the end of my question, when I run it on Ubuntu or the official docker image. Using `dotnet Asgard.Ihc.Api.dll' in all cases on all platforms. I'm on version 1.1.0 everywhere as well.

My code is a WCF client that calls a legacy SOAP/XML service with an invalid certificate. To combat this, I've added:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication = new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
    {
        CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
        RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
    };
```

However, judging by the exceptions, my best guess would be that the above code doesn't work on Linux.

Can anyone confirm or deny my suspicion?

Can I otherwise work around it? (Can I add the certificate to the docker container or host?)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
(An error occurred while sending the request.) ---> 
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> 
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> 
System.Net.Http.CurlException: SSL connect error
at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.ThrowIfCURLEError(CURLcode error)
at System.Net.Http.CurlHandler.MultiAgent.FinishRequest(StrongToWeakReference`1 easyWrapper, CURLcode messageResult)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceModelHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsync>d__58.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
at Asgard.Ihc.Controller.IhcController.<Connect>d__15.MoveNext() in /home/tvl/Asgard.Ihc.Api/src/Asgard.Ihc.Controller/IhcController.cs:line 72
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
at Asgard.Ihc.Api.IhcMonitor.Start() in /home/tvl/Asgard.Ihc.Api/src/Asgard.Ihc.Api/IhcMonitor.cs:line 23
at Asgard.Ihc.Api.Program.Main(String[] args) in /home/tvl/Asgard.Ihc.Api/src/Asgard.Ihc.Api/Program.cs:line 18
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is related to .NET Core not allowing SSL (in favor of TLS).

For legacy interop, I've raised an issue here

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1749